# Input type password value is showing as null

Tags: javascript, html

I don't understand why my  is not giving the value properly to my javascript variable. I have tried countless times, changing IDs and whatnot... still nothing... I searched everywhere for an answer... Please help

**HTML SNIPPET**

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit= "return validateForm()" class="registerform">
First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br/>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"><br/>
Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br/>
Phone Number: <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"><br/>
Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="myPass"><br/>
Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" id="confirmPass"><br/>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

**register.js**

```
...

    var password = document.getElementById("myPass").value;
    var confirmPassword = document.getElementById("confirmPass").value;

...

    function validateForm()
    {
        alert(password);
        alert(confirmPassword);
        error = '';
        var fNamePass = validateFName();
        var lNamePass = validateLName();
        var emailPass = validateEmail();
        var phonePass = validatePhone();
        var passwordPass = validatePassword();
        var passwordConfirmPass = validateConfirmationPassword();

...
```

in my alerts, the value keeps showing as null. Firebug shows me the value at null...
I'm not new to JS, but I feel like I'm doing something really silly here, but my mind is not catching it...

Comment: Please no jQuery and please no "variable error is not defined". I put "..." for a reason :p

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as \`getElementById\` not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: You should see that's not the issue

Comment: @Bergi, if it wasn't getting the element he would be getting a `cannot read property value of null`

Comment: AndroidNoob we are trying to help you here, I tested your code and moving the definition of your variables print them. Please be less arrogant and read the answers.

Comment: Ooops, right. I didn't see the `.value`. Also, `null` is an odd value. If it would refer to the properties from above, one would at least have expected `undefined` - though input `.value` always returns a string. As most of the answers have pointed out, it's odd you're accessing the `.value` property outside of the handler function (and therefore not getting the current value), but still one would not have expected `null`. If you can't do the debugging on your own, please provide the full code or a working demo.

Comment: can you show more of your code, as Bergi mentions you getting `null` is odd, either something is modifying the variable `password` before your validate function runs or there is something else wonky going on.

Comment: You need to provide code that actually reproduces the problem. A complete (but hopefully minimal) document that behaves as you described in your text.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are running into a scoping issue.
You need to make sure you pass the 'password' and 'confirmPassword' argument on to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Fine... do it the same way you did the rest

```
function validateForm()
{

    var password = validatePassword();
    var confirmPassword = validateConfirmPassword();
    alert(password);
    alert(confirmPassword);
    error = '';
    var fNamePass = validateFName();
    var lNamePass = validateLName();
    var emailPass = validateEmail();
    var phonePass = validatePhone();
    var passwordPass = validatePassword();
    var passwordConfirmPass = validateConfirmationPassword();
```

Comment: --He claimed he was setting everything the same way but obviously isn't

Answer (score -1):

You are setting the value of password and confirmpassword at time of load of document.

Move your definition of password and confirmpassword inside the function

```
var password, confirmPassword;
function validateForm()
{
    password = document.getElementById("myPass").value;
    confirmPassword = document.getElementById("confirmPass").value;
    alert(password);
    alert(confirmPassword);
```

Comment: I think that's wrong. If that logic is correct, why do the names validate?

Comment: because you are calling a function to get them instead of doing them at time of load

Comment: hmm, I have them in the same place as the password variables

Comment: ok... well theres about 6 of us all saying the same thing... have you tried it?

Comment: Also you arent doing it in the same place or the same fashion... you are setting pw at time of js load (rendering of doc) you are setting everything else with a check function that isnt called until your submit is done.

Comment: Yeah I tried it it worked. Thanks guys! But I'm really trying to understand why. My names are being validated through script load for some reason

Comment: @AndroidNoob, are they being autofilled by the browser when the page loads?

Comment: No, that's why I find it strange... The answers you all gave me are great, but it's not clear as to why the others were validating